# Does Teams support bot send attachments into conversations such as apk, pdf by REST?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to build a Bot that supports posting apk files into Teams using the BotFramework REST APIs.

I have tried `https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer-client-ss.msg/v3/conversations/${conversationId}/activities` but got the response:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadArgument",
        "message": "Unknown attachment type "
    }
}
```

I also tried `https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer-client-ss.msg/v3/conversations/${conversationId}/attachments` and got the response `statuscode:404`.

Does Teams not support this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send Attachments to Bot in Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059877/send-attachments-to-bot-in-teams)

Comment: Short answer: no, only images (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/botsconversation#picture-messages). Already answered in the duplicate I indicated

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Teams now [supports bots sending and receiving files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-files). As far as I can tell, there isn't a restriction on file types.